# Sniffing WhatsApp chat using Wireshark

Tags: man-in-the-middle, android, wireshark, whatsapp

Suppose two persons are using WhatsApp on Android. How can I see the communication between them if I have Wireshark running on a PC listening on network interface card?

I know the communication between them will be encrypted. How can I see the communication in Wireshark?

Comment: German IT news outlet [Heise has a nice description of their test rig online](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.heise.de%2Fsecurity%2Fartikel%2FTest-Hinter-den-Kulissen-der-WhatsApp-Verschluesselung-3165567.html&edit-text=).

Comment: I'm not seeing any difference between what you want and being able to see any 3rd party wifi traffic in Wireshark (especially since you expect the data to be encrypted). Are you simply asking how to capture another device's traffic on another computer? If so, there are numerous Wireshark tutorials for this.

Comment: @schroeder yes how to capture another device traffic on another computer, since Wireshark will be listening on my network Interface card.

Comment: Ok, then your question really is: how do I capture wifi traffic with Wireshark. Wireshark has tutorials on this, and many online tutorials from other sources.

Comment: @schroeder I am a good googler and tried googling too, can you mark to one tutorial that does this, thanks

Comment: https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/WLAN

Comment: @everyone since enabling monitor mode in window 7 is bummer , I found another tool which could be helpful for someone else who see this question https://www.acrylicwifi.com/en/

Comment: @Johnny Do you still need help with this?

Comment: @Lukas its resovled

Comment: Connect to your router using Wireshark's [SSH Remote Capture](https://ask.wireshark.org/question/2506/how-do-i-use-ssh-remote-capture-in-wireshark/).

Answer (score 4):

My suggestion is a little different to what you asked:

Download the app [Packet Capture](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.greyshirts.sslcapture&hl=en) from the Google Play Store and install it on your Phone.

Start the app, skip the generation of the root certificate (or generate one - this will help you decrypt SSL traffic), and start a capture.

You can then capture and analyze packets directly on your phone - without using wireshark on your PC.It is quite convenient for your specific case.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/75018)

Comment: You're right, it does not answer the OP's *question*, but I think it might help him solve his *problem* in an easier way than setting up everything to monitor the network traffic on the PC.

Comment: I think the main issue is that this assumes the OP has access to one of the phones, and it seems to me from the post, that he likely does not.  A comment on the question to ask this might be in order.

Comment: @Xander yes assume I dont have access, both User A and User B are using my Wifi though

Comment: @Lukas Installing the app might be simplest solution but I want to monitor it on computer.

Answer (score 1):

I would just set up a wireless router and have both android devices and the PC connect to it.  Most android devices have the ability to disable mobile data and thus force your connection to go over wireless.

Comment: I think the OP is assuming that the communication will be over wifi. I'm not sure this answers the question.

Comment: @schroeder yes its over wifi